Angular Libraries: 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files
A question, I don't know if this happens to anyone, I don't know how to fix it.
From an entrypoint (a component) I want to import the model of the other, but I get the error:
File is not under 'rootDir' 'packages'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files
For example, importing a material module that has all the modules inside is much more like it too, models that can be used in other components/entry-points of the angular lib, etc.
How can I fix it? Does anyone know?
I post photos of the structure
(https://i.sstatic.net/Jp60TaJ2.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/F80XKrVo.png)
(https://i.sstatic.net/fGHGSJ6t.png)
I tried to solve it in several ways, but none of them worked for me
I tried in tsconfig, angularjson, adding another angular, rootDir, exclude, include to the folders and nothing helped
In fact i have only one project. Its an angular library with 2 entry points, but the tsconfig i configure is the tsconfig of the entire library. This is the structure:
project
--ngx-rydex 
----dinamic-images 
-------models 
---------buttonForm.ts 
-------index.ts 
-------ng-package 
-------publicapi 
----recaptcha 
-------index.ts 
-------ng-package 
-------publicapi 

So, one model i have in dinamic-images component i want to use in recaptcha component

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? "I tried to solve it in several ways, but none of them worked for me" Have you tried moving all source files into rootDir?

I dont know really, the rootDir is not inside the tsconfig.json of the entire library. But when i put "rootDir":'./projects/ngx-rydex' it dosnt work

Have you read https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig/#rootDir

I tried to put "rootDir": ".". "rootDir": "*", "rootDir": "ngx-rydex", and none works :_C

I'm not sure if you can use a rootDir outside the project. Have you tried moving all sources into one project?

Please don't post code or code-like text in comments. It can't be formatted and is not readable. Edit your question and add it there. It sounds like you want to create reusable modules.

Ready! Sorry, edited is ready.
